# How can I decrease the opacity of an element by 0.1 every 100 milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so every 100 milliseconds, the opacity of a specified element decreases by 0.1. Here's my code:

```
       var loader = this.document.getElementById("loader");
       var op;
       for(op = 1.0; op > 0.0; op -= 0.1){
          window.setTimeout(function(){
              c.style.opacity = op.toString();
              loader.style.opacity = op.toString();
          }, 100)
       }
```

Am I potentially creating an infinite loop that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be with the `setInterval("yourFunctionHere()", 100)`
This will make the function you add run in the background and execute every 100 milliseconds. Just put your set opacity stuff into a function and execute it in the setInterval